# jqgrid parsererror

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid, xml-parsing

I am developing a web application using JSP & Servlet (IDE: Eclipse, Database: Oracle10). I am using jqGrid to display records in tabular format.

I am using `datatype: "xml"` for `jqgrid`.

I have a field in database for storing `address` and that field contains special characters like `,` `;` `&` etc. If any of the `Address` from database contains `&` then `jqgrid` is giving me message `response 200 ok, type: parsererror` and no data is shown in the grid , and if i remove the `&` from the database then it is not showing me this message and showing the data in grid.

```
 {name:'ADDRESS',index:'ADDRESS', width:80,sortable:true,editable:true}
```

so my question is that how should I send the data, which contains `&`

**Update1:**

I know that some characters are `XML reserved characters` like  `&` `<` and `>`, but then in that case i have to write `loop` for checking address on server side and if that address contains this reserved characters then i have to write them as `hexadecimal`, so is there any better way for doing this?

**Update2:**
I am using Servlets.
following is my code snippet.

```
out.print("<cell>" +ADDRESS +"A&BC"+"</cell>");//will show parsererror

out.print("<cell>" +ADDRESS +"A"+"</cell>");//will not show error, and data is diplayed
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: which server side technology you are using? can you post the server side code responsible for sending the data...

Comment: @dakait i have updated my code. i am using servlets for server side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To place information having XML reserved characters you have to use XML reserved characters `<![CDATA[...]]>` (see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) and [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3afirst_grid#php_and_mysql_example_file) for example) construct to produce correct XML data.

On the client side you should additionally use `autoencode: true` jqGrid option additionally.

Comment: who can answer jqgrid questions better than Oleg `:)`